# When to use power of 2 textures in XNA?

Tags: xna, textures

I hear a lot that power of 2 textures are better for performance reasons, but I couldn't find enough solid information about if it's a problem when using XNA. Most of my textures have random dimensions and I don't see much of a problem, but maybe VS profiler doesn't show that.

Comment: Its more a compatibility issue than a performance issue. Some graphics card require textures to be a power of 2, mostly older cards. In some cases if a graphics card is fed a non power of 2 texture then it will resize it up to the nearest power of 2. This is the only time performance comes into play.

Comment: So if performance loss is significant when feeding NPOT textures, I should choose between free RAM (manually pre- resizing textures) and lost frames?

Comment: The primary advantages to NPOT textures is they use less cpu ram and hard drive space. A lot of cards allocate a power of 2 chunk instead the actually dimensions of the image (this is what I meant by resize). So they use the same gpu ram either way while a NPOT uses slightly less bandwidth (shouldn't be a noticeable impact). For compatibility's sake I always go with POT textures. The only time performance should be significant is when the card is buggy or incompatible with the NPOT textures which will happen. So if you plan to try and make money off of it I strongly recommend POT textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, pow 2 textures are better. But most graphics cards should allow non pow 2 textures with a minimal loss of performance. However, if you use XNA reach profile, only pow 2 textures are allowed. And some small graphics cards only support the reach profile.

Comment: What if I load those non-power of two textures at runtime on reach profile?

Comment: Thing is there are no exceptions at least on PC. I haven't tried that on Xbox since most people say it's impossible to load textures at runtime, but I guess it's worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

XNA is really a layer built on top of DirectX. So any performance guidelines that goes for that will also apply for anything using XNA.

The VS profiler also won't really apply to the graphics specific things you are doing. That will need to be profiled separately by some tool that can check how the graphic card itself is doing. If the graphics card is struggling it won't show up as a high resource usage on your CPU, but rather as a slow rendering speed.